# matplotlib.patches.Polygon colors not rendering

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, colors, polygon, patch

```
for info, shape in zip(map.counties_info, map.counties):
    if info['FIPS'] in geoids:
        x = np.random.rand(1)[0]
        c = cmap(x)[:3]
        newc = rgb2hex(c)
        patches.append(Polygon(np.array(shape), color=newc, closed=True))

ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches))

plt.title('Counties with HQ of NYSE-Listed Firms: 1970')
plt.show()
```

produces this image:

[image: Output from the code]

My question is the code specifically asks for random colors in the polygons. If I print the values of newc and display them at a website that converts hex codes to colors, there is a wide range of different colors. But the output has only one. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a `PatchCollection` to have different colors for the individual patches, you have two options.

1. Using the colors of the original patches.
2. Using a colormap to determine the colors according to some array of values.

#### Using the colors of the original patches.

This approach is closest to the code from the question. It would require to set the argument `match_original=True` to the patch collection.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.patches
import matplotlib.collections

ar = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]])
cmap=plt.cm.jet
patches=[]

fig, ax=plt.subplots()

for i in range(5):
    x = np.random.rand(1)[0]
    c = cmap(x)[:3]
    poly = plt.Polygon(ar+i, color=c, closed=True)
    patches.append(poly)

collection = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches,match_original=True)
ax.add_collection(collection)

ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

#### Using a colormap to determine the colors according to some array of values.

This is probably easier to implement. Instead of giving each individual polygon a color, you would set an array of values to the `PatchCollection` and specify a colormap according to which the polygons are colorized.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.patches
import matplotlib.collections

ar = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]])
values = np.random.rand(5)
cmap=plt.cm.jet
patches=[]

fig, ax=plt.subplots()

for i in range(len(values)):
    poly = plt.Polygon(ar+i, closed=True)
    patches.append(poly)

collection = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches, cmap=cmap)
collection.set_array(values)
ax.add_collection(collection)
ax.autoscale()

plt.show()
```

Comment: It appears that I don't have the credibility to upvote your response. But it works (for others who may stumble here and are wondering if the suggested code works or not). Thank-you.